# Remove CSS classes without properties via regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have these CSS codes.

```
.class-1,
.class-2,
class-3 {
    }
.class-4,
class-5 {
}
.class-6,
class-7 {}
.not-empty-1 {font-size: 12;}
.not-empty-2 {
    font-size: 12;
}
.not-empty-3 {
font-size: 12;
}
```

I need to remove the CSS classes that don't have any properties.

I have tried this

```
.+\s{(\n.*|)}
```

https://regex101.com/r/8xFUDl/2

but it does not remove the previous classes like `.class-1, .class-2,` as you see in live example.

Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: I think that can be tricky, but for the current example perhaps like `[^{}\r\n]+(?:\r?\n[^{}\r\n]+)*{\s*}` https://regex101.com/r/QTzEu7/1

Comment: Are you set on using regex for this? It might be easier using a tokenizer. Also, likely easier to debug and extend/change later.

Comment: @Cully Would you explain more. I am up for any solution which is possible in PHP.

Comment: You may use this [`^(?:[^{}]*\n)*.+{\s*}\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/8xFUDl/3)

Comment: You basically step through the string one character at a time, and change state/take action depending on the character you find (e.g. if current state is "selector" and you see a "{" character, change state to "properties", etc.). It's sort of a state machine that takes characters as input.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Great, it works very well. Can you post it as an answer and explain how it works. I want to learn this. Thanks

Comment: Please update your question to mention `class-\d` is just an example, it can be anything, otherwise you're just wasting time to everyone, including yourself.

Comment: @user3631047 I could post it, but looking at the pattern of anubhava I think that would be the better answer if that also works for you.

Comment: @Thefourthbird: `^(?:[^{}\r\n]*\R)*+[^{]+{\s*}\s*` will be more efficient than what I posted earlier. Please post an answer as you were first to solve this. Making a pattern more efficient is a different issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments and credits for the final pattern to @[anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava), for the example data you could use:

```
^(?:[^{}\r\n]*\R)*+[^{}]+{\s*}\s*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^{}\r\n]*\R` Match 0+ times any char except `{` `}` or a newline and Unicode newline sequence
- `)*+` Close group and repeat 0+ times using a [possessive quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)
- `[^{}]+` Match 1+ times any char other than `{` or `}`
- `{\s*}` Match `{` and `}` with whitespaces in between (Note that `\s` also matches the newlines)
- `\s*` Match possible trailing whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJP5Vu/1)

Comment: @vivek_23 That is why I added a comment in the answer to use `[^{}]+` https://regex101.com/r/DcDFE2/1 I will update the whole pattern, thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged `PHP`, we can do a bit of string processing to make regex a bit simpler where we could just match a single `.some_class{some_props}` style and ignore all others who don't follow this property.

We can ignore all whitespaces, new lines and collect just text in a string with a space as a delimiter between each style. Now, we can explode on each one and see if it matches the style we want which has properties and collect only those and implode them later.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$str = '.class-1,
.class-2,
class-3 {
    }
.class-4,
class-5 {
}
.class-6,
class-7 {}
.not-empty-1 {font-size: 12;}
.not-empty-2 {
    font-size: 12;
}
.not-empty-3 {
font-size: 12;margin-top:25px;
}';

$new_str = '';

for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);++$i){
    if(strlen(trim($str[$i])) === 0) continue; // skip new lines,spaces, line feeds etc
    $new_str .= $str[$i];
    if($str[$i] == '}') $new_str .= ' ';
}

$results = [];

foreach(explode(" ",$new_str) as $css_style){
    if(preg_match('/^(.+?)\{(.+?)\}$/',$css_style,$matches)){
        $results[] = implode("\n",[$matches[1],"{\n ".$matches[2]."\n}"]);
    }
}


echo implode("\n\n",$results);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/67mXE